# Adjusting a value after math function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add a thousands comma to my output number for a simple web table that calculates the cumulative liters and gallons. However I am getting the wrong values. Can someone please help me decipher the below errors?

B8 returns 28 (which is correct)
B9 return 112,000 (which is correct)
B10 returns 112 (which should be 112,000)
B11 returns 25 (which should be 24,640)

```js
function toCommas(value) {
   return value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
 }
function calcule2(){
  var i=0; for (i=0;i<= 29;i++) {
    calcule();
  }
}
function calcule(){
  Excel2Html.B8.value=(Math.round((+parseFloat(Excel2Html.B6.value)*7)* 1))/ 1 ;
  Excel2Html.C8.value=(Math.round((+parseFloat(Excel2Html.C6.value)*7)* 1))/ 1 ;
  Excel2Html.D8.value=(Math.round((+parseFloat(Excel2Html.D6.value)*7)* 1))/ 1 ;
  Excel2Html.E8.value=(Math.round((+parseFloat(Excel2Html.E6.value)*7)* 1))/ 1 ;
  Excel2Html.F8.value=(Math.round((+parseFloat(Excel2Html.F6.value)*7)* 1))/ 1 ;

  Excel2Html.B9.value=toCommas((Math.round((+parseFloat(Excel2Html.B4.value)*parseFloat(Excel2Html.B8.value)*4)* 1))/ 1);
  Excel2Html.C9.value=(Math.round((+parseFloat(Excel2Html.B4.value)*parseFloat(Excel2Html.C8.value)*4)* 1))/ 1 ;
  Excel2Html.D9.value=(Math.round((+(parseFloat(Excel2Html.B4.value)*parseFloat(Excel2Html.D8.value))*4)* 1))/ 1 ;
  Excel2Html.E9.value=(Math.round((+(parseFloat(Excel2Html.B4.value)*parseFloat(Excel2Html.E8.value))*4)* 1))/ 1;
  Excel2Html.F9.value=(Math.round((+(parseFloat(Excel2Html.B4.value)*parseFloat(Excel2Html.F8.value))*4)* 1))/ 1 ;

  Excel2Html.B10.value=(Math.round((+parseFloat(Excel2Html.B9.value))* 1))/ 1;
  Excel2Html.C10.value=(Math.round((+parseFloat(Excel2Html.C9.value)+parseFloat(Excel2Html.B10.value))* 1))/ 1;
  Excel2Html.D10.value=(Math.round((+parseFloat(Excel2Html.D9.value)+parseFloat(Excel2Html.C10.value))* 1))/ 1;
  Excel2Html.E10.value=(Math.round((+parseFloat(Excel2Html.E9.value)+parseFloat(Excel2Html.D10.value))* 1))/ 1;
  Excel2Html.F10.value=(Math.round((+parseFloat(Excel2Html.F9.value)+parseFloat(Excel2Html.E10.value))* 1))/ 1;

  Excel2Html.B11.value=(Math.round((+parseFloat(Excel2Html.B10.value)*0.22)* 1))/ 1 ;
  Excel2Html.C11.value=(Math.round((+parseFloat(Excel2Html.C10.value)*0.22)* 1))/ 1 ;
  Excel2Html.D11.value=(Math.round((+parseFloat(Excel2Html.D10.value)*0.22)* 1))/ 1 ;
  Excel2Html.E11.value=(Math.round((+parseFloat(Excel2Html.E10.value)*0.22)* 1))/ 1 ;
  Excel2Html.F11.value=(Math.round((+parseFloat(Excel2Html.F10.value)*0.22)* 1))/ 1 ;
}
```

```html
<form name="Excel2Html">
<table border="0" margin="0" padding="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr height="20"px; style="border:0px;" >
<td style="height:20px; width: 231.483px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: 0px; border-bottom: 0px; border-right: 0px; border-left: 0px; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; text-align: left; ">MOB SIZE</td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 64.678px; background-color:#67823A; border-top: 0px; border-bottom: 0px; border-right: 0px; border-left: 0px; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#262626; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; "><input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B4" value="2000" size="8" style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 22.99425px; width: 64.678px; text-align: center; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#262626; font-weight: bold; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 67.817px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: 0px; border-bottom: 0px; border-right: 0px; border-left: 0px; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; text-align: left; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 77.161px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: 0px; border-bottom: 0px; border-right: 0px; border-left: 0px; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; text-align: left; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 80.3px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: 0px; border-bottom: 0px; border-right: 0px; border-left: 0px; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; text-align: left; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 81.322px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: 0px; border-bottom: 0px; border-right: 0px; border-left: 0px; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; text-align: left; "></td>
</tr>
<tr height=" 21.9945px;" style="border:0px;" >
<td style="height:20px; width: 231.483px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: 0px; border-bottom: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-right: 0px; border-left: 0px; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; text-align: left; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 64.678px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: 0px; border-bottom: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-right: 0px; border-left: 0px; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; text-align: left; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 67.817px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: 0px; border-bottom: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-right: 0px; border-left: 0px; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; text-align: left; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 77.161px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: 0px; border-bottom: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-right: 0px; border-left: 0px; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; text-align: left; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 80.3px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: 0px; border-bottom: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-right: 0px; border-left: 0px; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; text-align: left; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 81.322px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: 0px; border-bottom: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-right: 0px; border-left: 0px; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; text-align: left; "></td>
</tr>
<tr height=" 21.9945px;" style="border:0px;" >
<td style="height:20px; width: 231.483px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-bottom: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-right: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-left: solid 1px #C0C0C0; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; text-align: left; ">LITRES PER HEAD PER DAY</td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 64.678px; background-color:#67823A; border-top: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-bottom: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-right: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-left: solid 1px #C0C0C0; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#262626; text-align: left; "><input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B6" value="4" size="8" style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 21.9945px; width: 64.678px; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#262626; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 67.817px; background-color:#67823A; border-top: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-bottom: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-right: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-left: solid 1px #C0C0C0; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#262626; text-align: left; "><input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="C6" value="4" size="8" style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 21.9945px; width: 67.817px; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#262626; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 77.161px; background-color:#67823A; border-top: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-bottom: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-right: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-left: solid 1px #C0C0C0; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#262626; text-align: left; "><input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="D6" value="6" size="8" style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 21.9945px; width: 77.161px; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#262626; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 80.3px; background-color:#67823A; border-top: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-bottom: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-right: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-left: solid 1px #C0C0C0; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#262626; text-align: left; "><input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="E6" value="6" size="8" style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 21.9945px; width: 80.3px; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#262626; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 81.322px; background-color:#67823A; border-top: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-bottom: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-right: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-left: solid 1px #C0C0C0; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#262626; text-align: left; "><input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="F6" value="5" size="8" style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 21.9945px; width: 81.322px; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#262626; "></td>
</tr>
<tr height=" 22.99425px;" style="border:0px;" >
<td style="height:20px; width: 231.483px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-bottom: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-right: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-left: solid 1px #C0C0C0; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; text-align: left; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 64.678px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-bottom: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-right: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-left: solid 1px #C0C0C0; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; ">Nov</td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 67.817px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-bottom: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-right: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-left: solid 1px #C0C0C0; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; ">Dec</td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 77.161px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-bottom: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-right: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-left: solid 1px #C0C0C0; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; ">Jan</td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 80.3px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-bottom: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-right: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-left: solid 1px #C0C0C0; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; ">Feb</td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 81.322px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-bottom: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-right: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-left: solid 1px #C0C0C0; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; ">Mar</td>
</tr>
<tr height=" 21.9945px;" style="border:0px;" >
<td style="height:20px; width: 231.483px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-bottom: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-right: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-left: solid 1px #C0C0C0; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; text-align: left; ">LITRES PER HEAD PER WEEK</td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 64.678px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-bottom: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-right: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-left: solid 1px #C0C0C0; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; text-align: left; "><input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B8" value="28" size="8"disabled="disabled"  style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 21.9945px; width: 64.678px; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 67.817px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-bottom: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-right: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-left: solid 1px #C0C0C0; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; text-align: left; "><input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="C8" value="28" size="8"disabled="disabled"  style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 21.9945px; width: 67.817px; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 77.161px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-bottom: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-right: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-left: solid 1px #C0C0C0; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; text-align: left; "><input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="D8" value="42" size="8"disabled="disabled"  style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 21.9945px; width: 77.161px; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 80.3px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-bottom: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-right: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-left: solid 1px #C0C0C0; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; text-align: left; "><input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="E8" value="42" size="8"disabled="disabled"  style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 21.9945px; width: 80.3px; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 81.322px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-bottom: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-right: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-left: solid 1px #C0C0C0; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; text-align: left; "><input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="F8" value="35" size="8"disabled="disabled"  style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 21.9945px; width: 81.322px; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; "></td>
</tr>
<tr height=" 21.9945px;" style="border:0px;" >
<td style="height:20px; width: 231.483px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-bottom: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-right: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-left: solid 1px #C0C0C0; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; text-align: left; ">LITRES PER MOB PER MONTH</td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 64.678px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-bottom: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-right: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-left: solid 1px #C0C0C0; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; text-align: left; "><input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B9" value="224000" size="8"disabled="disabled"  style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 21.9945px; width: 64.678px; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 67.817px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-bottom: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-right: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-left: solid 1px #C0C0C0; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; text-align: left; "><input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="C9" value="224000" size="8"disabled="disabled"  style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 21.9945px; width: 67.817px; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 77.161px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-bottom: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-right: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-left: solid 1px #C0C0C0; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; text-align: left; "><input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="D9" value="336000" size="8"disabled="disabled"  style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 21.9945px; width: 77.161px; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 80.3px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-bottom: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-right: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-left: solid 1px #C0C0C0; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; text-align: left; "><input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="E9" value="336000" size="8"disabled="disabled"  style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 21.9945px; width: 80.3px; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 81.322px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-bottom: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-right: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-left: solid 1px #C0C0C0; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; text-align: left; "><input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="F9" value="280000" size="8"disabled="disabled"  style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 21.9945px; width: 81.322px; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; "></td>
</tr>
<tr height=" 21.9945px;" style="border:0px;" >
<td style="height:20px; width: 231.483px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-bottom: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-right: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-left: solid 1px #C0C0C0; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; text-align: left; ">CUMULATIVE LITRES</td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 64.678px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-bottom: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-right: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-left: solid 1px #C0C0C0; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; text-align: left; "><input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B10" value="224000" size="8"disabled="disabled"  style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 21.9945px; width: 64.678px; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 67.817px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-bottom: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-right: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-left: solid 1px #C0C0C0; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; text-align: left; "><input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="C10" value="448000" size="8"disabled="disabled"  style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 21.9945px; width: 67.817px; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 77.161px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-bottom: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-right: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-left: solid 1px #C0C0C0; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; text-align: left; "><input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="D10" value="784000" size="8"disabled="disabled"  style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 21.9945px; width: 77.161px; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 80.3px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-bottom: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-right: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-left: solid 1px #C0C0C0; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; text-align: left; "><input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="E10" value="1120000" size="8"disabled="disabled"  style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 21.9945px; width: 80.3px; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 81.322px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-bottom: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-right: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-left: solid 1px #C0C0C0; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; text-align: left; "><input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="F10" value="1400000" size="8"disabled="disabled"  style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 21.9945px; width: 81.322px; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; "></td>
</tr>
<tr height=" 21.9945px;" style="border:0px;" >
<td style="height:20px; width: 231.483px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-bottom: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-right: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-left: solid 1px #C0C0C0; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; text-align: left; ">CUMULATIVE GALLONS</td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 64.678px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-bottom: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-right: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-left: solid 1px #C0C0C0; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; text-align: left; "><input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B11" value="49280" size="8"disabled="disabled"  style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 21.9945px; width: 64.678px; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 67.817px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-bottom: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-right: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-left: solid 1px #C0C0C0; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; text-align: left; "><input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="C11" value="98560" size="8"disabled="disabled"  style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 21.9945px; width: 67.817px; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 77.161px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-bottom: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-right: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-left: solid 1px #C0C0C0; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; text-align: left; "><input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="D11" value="172480" size="8"disabled="disabled"  style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 21.9945px; width: 77.161px; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 80.3px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-bottom: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-right: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-left: solid 1px #C0C0C0; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; text-align: left; "><input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="E11" value="246400" size="8"disabled="disabled"  style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 21.9945px; width: 80.3px; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 81.322px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-bottom: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-right: solid 1px #C0C0C0; border-left: solid 1px #C0C0C0; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; text-align: left; "><input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="F11" value="308000" size="8"disabled="disabled"  style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 21.9945px; width: 81.322px; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; font-family:Ubuntu; color:#666666; "></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: `(Math.round((+parseFloat(Excel2Html.B6.value)*7)* 1))/ 1` (and so on) is very unnecessary. `+parseFloat` is redundant - `parseFloat` returns a number and the unary `+` converts that...to a number. Multiplying by `1` would result in the same number. Dividing by `1` would do the same. Each of these would also force the already numeric value to be converted to numeric, which is still unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks, however I am not familiar with JS, how would I add toLocaleString to loop above? I have more data to loop through, that was just one column of the table that I need to create? @VLAZ

Comment: why you did not pass value to tocomma function Excel2Html.B10.value=toCommas((Math.round((+parseFloat(Excel2Html.B9.value))* 1))/ 1);

Comment: I tried that and it still doesnt change it to thousands

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use `toLocaleString`:

```
const myNum = 1000;
console.log(myNum.toLocaleString()) // 1,000
```

Comment: How would I do that for B11 for example?

Comment: I've tried using to locale string and its not calculating correctly

Comment: Try assign `(Math.round((+parseFloat(Excel2Html.B10.value)*0.22)* 1))/ 1` into a variable and then call toLocaleString.

What is the output you're getting?

Comment: var B9cell = document.Excel2Html.B9.value;
B9cell=(Excel2Html.B4.value*Excel2Html.B8.value*4).toLocaleString();

This didnt even work @DSCH

Comment: What is the value you're getting?

Comment: Yay I got it to work by adding it to a variable and then converting that variable with my function that adds the thousand commas!